# Can we deploy web application as a folder instead of war file in JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x

I am having two queries
 1.  Can I deploy web application as a folder instead of war file in JBoss AS 7?
 2.  If not ,how to update the JSP or html or js files with out building/deploying the war file again?

Answer (score 3):

JBoss supports the ability to deploy an archive file or as an exploded directory. To explode a Java EE archive, unzip the archive to a directory that is named the **same** as the archive file.   As long as the directory name has the correct extension (.war, .ear, etc.) JBoss will deploy the directory normally.  So if your war file has name `HelloWorld.war`, your exploded directory name should be `HelloWorld.war` too.

Please also note that it is recommended to edit your `deployment-scanner` in the `standalone.xml` configuration file and changing `auto-deploy-exploded` property back to **false** for exploded deployment. Quote from [JBoss 7.1 Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Application+deployment):

> Manual deploy mode is strongly recommended for exploded content, as
>   exploded content is inherently vulnerable to the scanner trying to
>   auto-deploy partially copied content.

**Edit:**

Please see link https://community.jboss.org/thread/200114. Looks like this is a confirmed bug in JBoss 7.1.1 that JBoss ignores the configuration in jsp-configuration and does not reload modified jsp. It is fixed in 7.1.2. You need to build 7.1.2 nightly build yourself. Or talk to JBoss Support if you have Enterprise support.

Comment: Thanks, i am able to deploy the extracted folder, but if i update any JSP or HTML or JS file , and update the same in Jboss ,it is redeploying the whole application again.Is there any way , not to redeploy the application? In some servers like Apache Tomcat , it wont redeploy the application,it will deploy only the modified UI files.