# Deploy .WAR in JBoss like tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7, jboss7.x

I am familiar with tomcat. We create a project in eclipse with server.xml and some .config file. We generate the .WAR file. We copy this war file to our production server webapps folder, After that a new folder will be generated with same name inside webapps folder. We change production server configuration there( in folder).

One of our client wants to deploy war on his JBoss server. We tried to deploy war on JBoss by copying war to /standalone/deployments/ folder.
Projects runs but no new folder is generated. So my problem is how we can change in configuration on jboss like we do on tyomcat7?

Comment: You didn't read the manual? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Application+deployment

Comment: I read it. My war is deployed sucessfully, But my problem is how i change config files which is in this war file? I tried by  auto-deploy-exploded="true" but i am not getting folder.

Answer (score 0):

Got It.
[Can we deploy web application as a folder instead of war file in JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562898/can-we-deploy-web-application-as-a-folder-instead-of-war-file-in-jboss-as-7#)

change deployment scanner to this

```
<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-exploded="true"/>
```

And export your war file content to a directory and it should have same name like .war file.
For example:-

If .war name is project.war then directory name should be project.war. Copy this directory to  /standalone/deployments/ folder. And restart JBoss. Now if you change in directory config then changes will appear in project